# Postgres alternatives for DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO read_module, set_action, set_module procedures

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, amazon-aurora, ora2pg

I have an Oracle stored procedure which I'm migrating to PostgreSQL.

There are `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_MODULE`, `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION`, and `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE` procedures in the stored procedure for which I'm unable to find alternatives in Postgres.

What could be the closest alternatives for these procedures in Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parameter `application_name`:

Example:

```
 postgres=# show application_name;
 application_name 
------------------
 psql
(1 row)

postgres=# select application_name from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();
 application_name 
------------------
 psql
(1 row)

postgres=# set application_name='myapp';
SET
postgres=# select application_name from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();
 application_name 
------------------
 myapp
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Here is a possible solution to implement action and module:

```
begin;
BEGIN

set application_name='my_module:my_action';
SET

select application_name from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();
  application_name   
---------------------
 my_module:my_action
(1 row)

commit;
COMMIT

select application_name from pg_stat_activity where pid = pg_backend_pid();
  application_name   
---------------------
 my_module:my_action
(1 row)

do
$$
declare
 v_module text;
 v_action text;
 v_application_name text;
 v_pos int;
begin
 select application_name into v_application_name
 from pg_stat_activity 
 where pid = pg_backend_pid();
 v_pos = position(':' in v_application_name); 
 if (v_pos > 0)
 then
  v_module = substring(v_application_name, 1, v_pos - 1);
  v_action = substring(v_application_name, v_pos + 1);
  raise notice 'v_module=%, v_action=%', v_module, v_action;
 end if;
end;
$$;
NOTICE:  v_module=my_module, v_action=my_action
DO
```

Comment: Note that `set application_name` only works if autocommit is enabled.

Comment: Not exactly: `If SET (or equivalently SET SESSION) is issued within a transaction that is later aborted, the effects of the SET command disappear when the transaction is rolled back. Once the surrounding transaction is committed, the effects will persist until the end of the session, unless overridden by another SET.`

Comment: Yes, but `pg_stat_activity` doesn't change during a transaction. But it's probably more interesting to _other_ sessions anyway (at least that's usually the intention of using `dbms_application_info` in Oracle)

Comment: Thanks! How can I use application_name for `read_module`, `set_action`, and `set_module` procedures?

Comment: See my updated anwser: you can try to adapt this code to your application PL/pgSQL or write something similar in another language.